# samba server Authentication; #security = user not showing

Tags: samba, raspberrypi

while following instructions to set up a samba server one of the steps mentioned the following; (after opening the file using 'sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf'

**Search for the section marked ##### Authentication #####**

**Change the text**

## security = user

**to**

**security = user**

However I can not find the line **# security = user** in the lines on my screen.

Is it possible to just add **security = user** somewhere in the authentication part? If so, any particular place or does this not matter?

Thanks in advance,

Menno

Answer (score 0):

Strange you did not find it. Anyway, you can safely add this mention or even do nothing as this is the default setting.